# InitBinder in spring 4.3.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
<form:select path="branchID" items="${branches}" ></form:select>
```

I cannot bind object when post a request to the parent object and I read that I should @initBinder to convert the object, but I cannot find the @initBinder in spring web 4.3.7 it is available in 4.3.8 and I cannot change the spring version any replacement ?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you want to bind a selected item from `branches` list to `branchID`?

Comment: yes , branches is a list of Branch and branchID is an object of Branch also